# Find The Simplest Sum

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to solve [The Simplest Sum](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hackerrank-hiring-contest/challenges/the-simplest-sum/problem) from hackerrank. Could anyone please let me know how I can make this code much effective in terms of time and space complexity?

---

> You are just learning to code and are finished with loops and
>   functions. Now, you are given the following pseudocode:
>
> ```
> /*
>  * The function has two integer parameters: k and n
>  * The function returns the value of sum
>  */
> function f(k, n) {
>     sum = 0;
>
>     for (i = 1; i ≤ n; i += 1) {
>         sum += i;
>         i *= k;
>     }
>
>     return sum;
> }
> ```
>
> For three given integers *k*, *a*, and *b*, find the value of *S* mod (10⁹ + 7), where *S* is defined as:
>
> $$S=\sum_{n=a}^b f(k,n)$$
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line of the input is an integer *Q*, the total number of
>   queries. Each of the next *Q* lines contains three space separated
>   integers *k*, *a*, and *b*.

#### Constraints

• 1 ≤ *Q* ≤ 10⁵
  • 2 ≤ *k* ≤ 10⁵
  • 1 ≤ *a* ≤ *b* ≤ 10^18   *Constraints left out from the problem description as quoted in 2018*

> #### Output Format
>
> For each query, print the value of *S* mod (10⁹ + 7) on a new line.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4
> 2 1 5
> 3 1 5
> 4 1 5
> 5 1 5
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 14
> 13
> 10
> 5
> ```
>
> #### Explanation
>
> - Query 2 1 5
>
>   ```
>   f(2, 1) = 1
>   f(2, 2) = 1
>   f(2, 3) = 4
>   f(2, 4) = 4
>   f(2, 5) = 4
>   ```
>
>   So, *S* = f(2, 1)+f(2, 2)+f(2, 3)+f(2, 4)+f(2, 5) = 14
> - Query 3 1 5
>
>   ```
>   f(3,1) = 1
>   f(3,2) = 1
>   f(3,3) = 1
>   f(3,4) = 5
>   f(3,5) = 5
>   ```
>
>   So, *S* = f(3,1)+f(3,2)+f(3,3)+f(3,4)+f(3,5) = 13
> - Query 4 1 5
>
>   ```
>   f(4,1) = 1
>   f(4,2) = 1
>   f(4,3) = 1
>   f(4,4) = 1
>   f(4,5) = 6
>   ```
>
>   So, *S* = f(4,1)+f(4,2)+f(4,3)+f(4,4)+f(4,5) = 10
> - Query 5 1 5
>
>   ```
>   f(5,1) = 1
>   f(5,2) = 1
>   f(5,3) = 1
>   f(5,4) = 1
>   f(5,5) = 1
>   ```
>
>   So, *S* = f(5,1)+f(5,2)+f(5,3)+f(5,4)+f(5,5) = 5

---

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class maxSum {

static int simplestSum(int k, int a, int b) {
    int count = 1;
    int totalSum = 0;
    while(count <= b) {
        int z = maxSum(k, a);
        int mul = k*a;
        if(mul < b) {
            totalSum = totalSum + (z*(k*a));
        }else {
            totalSum = totalSum + (z*((b-count)+1));
        }

        count = count + (k*a);
        a = count;
    }
    return totalSum;
}

static int maxSum(int k , int a) {
    int sum = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= a; i += 1) {
         sum += i;
         i *= k;
     }
     return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++){
        int k = in.nextInt();
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int result = simplestSum(k, a, b);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    in.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) It would be appropriate to name the origin of this problem statement and may be helpful to provide a link (there is a *grey area* in the formula?!). With a successfully designed "mathematical programming problem", no amount of cleverness in *coding* a brute force approach should be fast enough: you need a better algorithm.

Comment: @greybeard Please , find the link for problem statement https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hackerrank-hiring-contest/challenges/the-simplest-sum/problem
. I understand brute force approach is not the best one for this but i am not sure about other algorithm for this problem .

Answer (score 1):

(I do not intend to address the *better algorithm* angle beyond stating that this is another hackerrank problem seeking *[the series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) for a sequence* and quoting one advice: *Pen down a few iterations yourself and you will find a way to compute the function value directly.*)

Following the code presented top to bottom:

- [Document/comment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) your code. In the code.
  What is the class about, each method, its parameters?
- Don't specify sweeping `include`s you don't use.
  Here, just use `java.util.Scanner` *and not a single `include`*
- Class names should be *CamelCase*: `class SimplestSum`
- provided *arithmetic assignment operators* and *conditional expressions*, I'd code accumulating
  `totalSum += z * (mul < b ? k*a : (b-count)+1);`
- you introduce a variable for `k*a`, but use it in one place out of three, only.
- at the end of `simplestSum()`'s code, I think it *does* try and use a *series*: explain in the method comment.
  Accumulation may exceed the range of `int` (applies to `maxSum()` as well)
- `maxSum()`'s indentation is off ever so slightly
- `maxSum()` does *not* try and use a *series*
- do not *open code* closing `AutoCloseable`s: use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
- in `main()`, using single letter variable names from the problem statement suggests itself - not so for `nQueries`.
  And *why* introduce another variable, *why* name it `a0` (instead of `query` or even `q` (OK for an iteration variable in an inner loop, especially when not used otherwise))
- *a* and *b* are input using `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()` where the *Constraints* allow *≤ 10^18*
  depending on where and how large inputs are handled, this will necessitate declaring variables/parameters to handle numbers beyond the range of `int` more likely than not.